# Query much slower in SQL Server 2012 compared to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

Recently we moved our database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012. Since then we are experiencing performance problems when we use the following query:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Candidates.CandidateID AS Candidates_CandidateID, 
    dbo.Candidates.DateCreated AS Candidates_DateCreated, 
    dbo.Candidates.Gender AS Candidates_Gender, 
    dbo.Titles.TitleName AS Titles_TitleName, 
    dbo.Addresses.CityName AS Addresses_CityName, 
    dbo.Countries.CountryName AS Candidates_CountryName, 
    dbo.Candidates.PhoneNumber AS Candidates_PhoneNumber, 
    dbo.Candidates.MobilePhoneNumber AS Candidates_MobilePhoneNumber, 
    dbo.Candidates.BirthDate AS Candidates_BirthDate, 
    dbo.vwConcatenatedBranchesPerCandidate.Branches_BrancheName, 
    dbo.States.StateName AS States_StateName, 
    dbo.SubStates.SubStateName AS SubStates_SubStateName, 
    dbo.Candidates.StateDate AS Candidates_StateDate, 
    dbo.Candidates.Nationality AS Candidates_Nationality, 
    dbo.Candidates.AvailableFromDate AS Candidates_AvailableFromDate, 
    dbo.Candidates.AvailableUntilDate AS Candidates_AvailableUntilDate, 
    dbo.Availabilities.AvailabilityName AS Availabilities_AvailabilityName, 
    dbo.AvailableDurations.AvailableDurationName AS AvailableDurations_AvailableDurationName, 
    dbo.Candidates.HoursPerWeekMin AS Candidates_HoursPerWeekMin, 
    dbo.Candidates.HoursPerWeekMax AS Candidates_HoursPerWeekMax, 
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastLetter.Candidates_DateLastLetter, 
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastEmail.Candidates_DateLastEmail, 
    dbo.Candidates.FirstName AS Candidates_FirstName, 
    dbo.Candidates.Initials AS Candidates_Initials, 
    dbo.Candidates.Infix AS Candidates_Infix, 
    dbo.Candidates.Surname AS Candidates_Surname, 
    dbo.vwConcatenatedEmailAddressesPerCandidate.Email AS EmailAddresses_EmailAddress, 
    dbo.vwConcatenatedCurrentFunctionNamesPerCandidate.Candidates_CurrentFunctionNames, 
    dbo.CandidateSources.SourceName AS CandidateSources_SourceName,
    dbo.Candidates.CandidateSourceText AS Candidates_CandidateSourceText, CandidateIsActiveInAMatch.Candidates_ActiveInOtherMatch, 
    dbo.vwCandidatesUsersFullName.Candidates_FullUserName, 
    dbo.Candidates.Remark AS Candidates_Remark, 
    dbo.Candidates.HasWorkedForUs AS Candidates_HasWorkedForUs, 
    dbo.GenerateFullName(dbo.Candidates.Surname, dbo.Candidates.FirstName, dbo.Candidates.Initials, dbo.Candidates.Infix) AS Candidates_FullName, 
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastMarketingMail.Candidates_DateMarketingMail, 
    dbo.Addresses.StreetName AS Addresses_StreetName, 
    dbo.Addresses.PostalCode AS Addresses_PostalCode, 
    dbo.Candidates.AvailabilityNote, 
    dbo.Candidates.Greeting, 
    dbo.Candidates.StartDate AS Candidates_StartDate, 
    dbo.Candidates.EndDate AS Candidates_EndDate
FROM         
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastEmail RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CandidateSources RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Candidates LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastMarketingMail ON dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.vwCandidatesLastMarketingMail.Candidates_CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Titles ON dbo.Candidates.TitleID = dbo.Titles.TitleID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vwCandidatesUsersFullName ON dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.vwCandidatesUsersFullName.Candidates_CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.CandidateIsActiveInAMatch() AS CandidateIsActiveInAMatch ON dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = CandidateIsActiveInAMatch.CandidateID ON 
    dbo.CandidateSources.CandidatesSourceID = dbo.Candidates.CandidateSourceID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vwConcatenatedCurrentFunctionNamesPerCandidate ON 
    dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.vwConcatenatedCurrentFunctionNamesPerCandidate.CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vwConcatenatedEmailAddressesPerCandidate ON dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.vwConcatenatedEmailAddressesPerCandidate.CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AvailableDurations ON dbo.Candidates.AvailableDurationID = dbo.AvailableDurations.AvailableDurationID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Availabilities ON dbo.Candidates.AvailabilityID = dbo.Availabilities.AvailabilityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vwConcatenatedBranchesPerCandidate ON dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.vwConcatenatedBranchesPerCandidate.CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.States ON dbo.Candidates.StateID = dbo.States.StateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.SubStates ON dbo.Candidates.SubStateID = dbo.SubStates.SubStateID AND dbo.States.StateID = dbo.SubStates.StateID ON 
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastEmail.Candidates_CandidateID = dbo.Candidates.CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vwCandidatesLastLetter ON dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.vwCandidatesLastLetter.Candidates_CandidateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Countries INNER JOIN
    dbo.Addresses ON dbo.Countries.CountryID = dbo.Addresses.CountryID ON dbo.Candidates.AddressID = dbo.Addresses.AddressID
```

The query uses some subviews that use a custom user defined aggregate concatenate function (the views start with vwConcatenated...) and some subviews use the following query (they all end with LastEmail, LastLetter etc...):

```
SELECT        
    dbo.Candidates.CandidateID AS Candidates_CandidateID, 
    MAX(dbo.Actions.DateCreated) AS Candidates_DateLastEmail
FROM
    dbo.Candidates 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Actions_Candidates 
ON 
    dbo.Candidates.CandidateID = dbo.Actions_Candidates.CandidateID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Actions 
ON 
    dbo.Actions_Candidates.ActionID = dbo.Actions.ActionID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.ActionTypes 
ON 
    dbo.Actions.ActionTypeID = dbo.ActionTypes.ActionTypeID
WHERE
    (dbo.ActionTypes.ActionTypeCodeInternal = N'CANDIDATE_EMAIL') OR
    (dbo.ActionTypes.ActionTypeCodeInternal = N'SENT_EMAIL')
GROUP BY dbo.Candidates.CandidateID
```

In SQL Server 2012 this query throws a warning containing the following message: Operator used tempdb to spill data during execution with spill level 1.

It also looks like the query ins't cached because when I run the same query for the second time it takes just as long as the previous attempt. When I run the same query twice in SQL 2005 then the second time it returns within the seconds.

Why do SQL Server 2012 and 2005 handle the query so differently and why is it much slower in SQL 2012?

Links to execution plans

- [SQL 2005 EP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/205541509/SQL%202005%20ep.xml)
- [SQL 2012 EP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/205541509/SQL%202012%20ep.xml)

Comment: How about "not-enough-perfomance" server for SQL Server 2012? Is it the same HW?

Comment: Unless you have the same indexes, data and updated statistics, you can't compare the performance. Compare the execution plans of both queries to see what's different.

Comment: How is your server doing for RAM?  SQL 2012 is almost certain to require more RAM.  (is PerfMon showing much paging/swapping?)

Comment: The database on SQL Server 2012 is an exact copy of SQL Server 2005. The execution plans are completely different. The results are the same but how they reach the result is totally different.

Comment: Server is using 2GB of RAM and has a total of 16GB

Comment: Is it possible to share the two execution plans?

Comment: not sure what could have changed to cause your performance loss, but this [breaking changes list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143179.aspx) might help

Comment: I've added the execution plans

Comment: Database is still in compatibility mode for SQL Server 2005

Comment: Build numbers please. 2012 had some issues with the query optimizer at the beginning. So, whichversion do you use EXACTLY?

Comment: Version is 11.0.3128.0

Comment: The execution plan for SQL Server 2012 is cached 1368 KB and for SQL Server 2005 533 B

Comment: Just did an update stats on all tables and now the query is much faster. From 9-11 seconds to 2 seconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926841/sql-server-2012-slower-than-2005?rq=1